# Does "if any" in a foreach loop exist?

Tags: powershell, iis, foreach, http-status-codes

I am trying to comb through a WebServer's app pools to detect the HTTP Response codes of each app.  I am using a `foreach` loop to check for the response to be 200, but if one of the responses is something other than a 200 I need the `foreach` loop to continue and check all the other app pools.

```
$appPool = Get-WebApplication
foreach ($a in $appPool) {
    $app = $a.Attributes[0].Value;
    $url = "http://localhost$app/apitest/index"
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $HTTP_Response = try{
        $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    } catch {
        $exceptionMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $exceptionItem = $app
    }
    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

    if ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
        $errorcode = 0
    } elseif ($HTTP_Status -ne 200) {
        $errorcode = 1
    } else {
        $errorcode = 2
    }
}
```

I'm finding that it doesn't matter what any app pools return because the loop just exits with whatever the last app returns.  If app 3 returns a 503 but the last app returns a 200, then the `foreach` loop returns a 200 and exits with `$errorcode = 0`.

How do I change this code to check all app pools but exit with a different error code if an app in the middle does not have a 200 status code?

Answer (score 3):

One way you can do this is to embrace the returned booleans as a list and just check that the list contains the value. For example:

```
$results =  foreach($n in 1..10) { 
    $n -eq 5 
}

if ($results -contains $true) {
    Write-Host "There was a 5"
}
```

For your example, I guess:

```
$appPool = get-webapplication
$results = foreach($a in $appPool) {

    $app = $a.Attributes[0].Value;
    $url = "http://localhost$app/apitest/index"
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $HTTP_Response = try { 
        $HTTP_Request.GetResponse() 
    } catch { 
        $exceptionMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $exceptionItem = $app
    }
    [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode -ne 200
}

if ($results -contains $true) {
    $errorcode = 1
} else {
    $errorcode = 0
}
```

I didn't want to clutter the example, but I might actually just do:

```
$errorcode = $results -contains $true -as [int]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would pre-set `$errorcode` before entering the loop, and change its value only when the status code for a request is not 200.

```
$errorcode = 0
foreach ($a in $appPool) {
    ...
    if ($HTTP_Response.StatusCode.value__ -ne 200) {
        $errorcode = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach too

Comment: This wouldn't solve my problem because the 1st iteration of the foreach loop may not equal 200, so errorcode would be set to 1.  But then the next iteration might be equal to 200 and it would change the errorcode to 0.

Comment: @RaptorPete this method would not reset the errorcode to 0 ever, after the loop starts, which I think is what you wanted.

Comment: @briantist I would want it to set $errorcode=1 when any of the ($a in $appPool) return something other than 200.  That way, I will be alerted if any ($a in $appPool) on this particular server is failing.

Does this foreach method that you provided change  back $errorcode=0 if, for example, the last $a in the $appPool does return a status of 200?

Comment: @RaptorPete It was my answer, and no, it does not reset `$errorcode` to 0 within the loop. What even gave you that idea? Nothing in the code I posted does (or even suggests) that.

Comment: @RaptorPete my answer is the other one, this answer is Ansgar's, but yes both answers do what you want.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers No, you're right. And I apologize.  I deleted my previous 2 comments because I realized that I was an idiot in asking them.